# Error running maven packaged project, ApplicationRunner fails

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have tried all corresponding posts solutions I have found and didn't have any success.

This is my error:

> 2019-07-12 07:59:42.713 ERROR 3304 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:726)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:713)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>           at de.opentiming.feigWS.FeigWsApplication.main(FeigWsApplication.java:12)
>   [classes!/:0.2-SNAPSHOT]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [feigWS-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.2-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [feigWS-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.2-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   [feigWS-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.2-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   [feigWS-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.2-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>           at de.opentiming.feigWS.FeigWsApplicationRunner.run(FeigWsApplicationRunner.java:32)
>   ~[classes!/:0.2-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:723)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>           ... 14 common frames omitted

I packaged my project my maven project with mvn package.
Build succesful!

But when i start java -jar i get an error from application starter.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.opentiming.feigws</groupId>
    <artifactId>feigWS</artifactId>
    <version>0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>feigWS</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repository</id>
            <url>file:///${project.basedir}/maven-repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.feig</groupId>
            <artifactId>OBIDISC4J</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My ApplicationRunner:

```
    package de.opentiming.feigWS;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.*;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.*;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.*;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;


    @SpringBootApplication
    //@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, WebClientAutoConfiguration.class, PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class, ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.class})
    @ComponentScan
    @Configuration


    public class FeigWsApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(FeigWsApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: First I would recommend not to use Spring Boot 1.X anymore better use Spring Boot 2.X furthermore why do you use `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration` in your Spring Boot Application class?

Comment: I realy would like to use the newest version, but i don't know where to change that so my mvn package uses it corectly. in my pom.xml are multiple spring dependencies.
I will immediatly try without, '@ComponentScan' and '@Configuration'.

Comment: I found where in my pom.xml to change my version. But with your recommedations it still doesn't work and gives me again that error.